# Replace padding of body using jquery

Tags: jquery, padding, document-body

I am trying to replace the padding of the body when an element is closed using jquery. But, I am having trouble accomplishing this.

My close button works fine, just trying to figure out how to replace the padding.

Here is my JS:

```
$('#hide').click(function() {
   $('#countdown-wrap').slideUp('fast');
   $('body').animate({ paddingTop: 45px });
   return false;
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$('body').animate({ paddingTop: 45px });` -> `$('body').animate({ paddingTop: 45 });`

`45px` is not a var in js like it is in css, so you either need to use a normal integer `45` or a string `"45px"`.

Answer (score 2):

your 45px should be quoted

```
$('body').animate({ paddingTop: '45px' });
```